# If a,b,c are the 3 edges of a triangle then prove that $2<\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}-\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}≤3$?

Tags: geometry, inequality

What I found, that is
Since the sum of any 2 sides of a triangle is greater than the third if follows that $a + b > c$ or $\dfrac{a+b}{c} > 1$ and so $\dfrac{a+b}{c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b} > 1 + 1 + 1 =3$

But I also need to prove $\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc} \le 1$

Right?

Comment: If $a = b = c = 0.001$ (which forms a tiny equilateral triangle) then $\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc} = -2994$. Are you sure you aren't missing a condition?

Comment: It was a mistake. It will be cube instead of square. Sorry. Bow the question is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, for $a = b = c = 1$, we have $\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc} = 3 > 1$, so you need to work a bit harder to bound the other terms.

Comment: Then how can I prove that?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

Use Ravi's substitution: $a = x+y, b = x+z, c = y+z$ for positive $x,y,z$. (This is motivated by the incircle).

Then the expression (according to WA) simplifies to

$$\frac{8 x y z}{(x+y) (x+z) (y+z)}+2.$$

Now we need to show

$$0 < \frac{8 x y z}{(x+y) (x+z) (y+z)} \le 1.$$

The LHS is obvious. For the RHS, note that by AM GM,

$$x+y \ge 2\sqrt{xy}$$
$$x+z \ge 2 \sqrt{xz}$$
$$y+z \ge 2 \sqrt{yz}.$$

Therefore,

$$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z) \ge 8xyz$$

and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma:**
>   In $\Delta ABC$,we have
>   $$1<\cos{A}+\cos{B}+\cos{C}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$
>   Proof:
>   since
>   \begin{align*}\cos{A}+\cos{B}+\cos{C}&=2\cos{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{A-B}{2}}-2\cos^2{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}+1\\
> &=4\cos{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}+1\\
> &=4\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}+1\\
> &>1
> \end{align*}
>   on the other hand
>   $$\cos{A}+\cos{B}+\cos{C}\le \cos{A}+2\cos{\dfrac{B+C}{2}}=\cos{A}+2\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$

so 
$$\Longleftrightarrow 1<\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}+\dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}+\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$
so
$$\Longleftrightarrow 2<\dfrac{a+b}{c}+\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}-\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}\le 3$$